# Inf to Sup conversion

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

The article I am reading asserts the following:
$$ \inf_{\phi,\psi} [\int_X \phi \,d\mu+\int_Y \psi \,d\nu\ ; \phi(x) + \psi(y) \geq -c(x,y)] \\ = - \sup_{\phi,\psi} [\int_X \phi \,d\mu+\int_Y \psi \,d\nu \ ; \phi(x) + \psi(y) \leq c(x,y)]$$
I know that $\inf f = - \sup -f$. So why isn't the expression:
$$- \sup_{\phi,\psi} [\int_X -\phi \,d\mu+\int_Y -\psi \,d\nu \ ; -\phi(x) - \psi(y) \leq c(x,y)]$$
(i.e. just multiply both expressions in the $\inf$ by $-1$)

Comment: It doesn’t look right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry I could not see any problem in it. Just simply replacing the name of functions in your formula
$$
- \sup [\int_X -\phi \,d\mu+\int_Y -\psi \,d\nu \ ; -\phi(x) - \psi(y) \leq c(x,y)]
$$
by $f=-\phi$, $g=-\psi$, we get
$$
- \sup [\int_X f \,d\mu+\int_Y g \,d\nu \ ; f(x) + g(y) \leq c(x,y)]
$$
The only thing is that I think there is a typo of your $\sup_{x,y}$. It is $\sup_{\phi,\psi}$.

Otherwise if I am wrong, then there *is* a problem in your formula in the article.

Comment: that wasn't a typo. it actually just said $\inf$ and $\sup$ and i assumed that it was over x,y. But after looking at your comments and the formula, i see they are over the functions - o.w. my formula wouldn't make sense. So I fixed this.

Comment: however, I don't see why you can just make this replacement without changing the meaning of sup -- ie why does $\sup_{\psi,\phi}$ = $\sup_{f,g}$?

Comment: @yoshi Because they are just "local variables". So they can replace each other. For example, $$\sum_{i=1}^k h(i) = \sum_{j=1}^k h(j).$$ Right?

Comment: Okay, the suggestion is that they are like "indicies". But I think of this $\sup$ as a functional of 2 inputs. So I'm thinking maybe "analgous" to $f(x,y)$. But if I change $x \rightarrow -x$, $y \rightarrow -y$: this function will, in general, look different, right? (e.g. like an odd function)

Comment: Consider these. $$\sum_{i,j \in \Bbb{Z}} h(i,j) = \sum_{s,t \in \Bbb{Z}} h(-s,-t)$$ $$\sum_{i,j \in \Bbb{N}} h(i,j) \neq \sum_{s,t \in \Bbb{N}} h(-s,-t)$$

Comment: okay i see, thanks!